# Stopping criteria for optim/SANN in R not working

Tags: r, optimization

**Issue 1**
I have an objective function, `gFun(modelOutput,l,u)`, which returns 0 if the simulated output is in interval `[l,u]`, otherwise it returns a positive(!) number.

```
OFfun <- function(params) {
  out <- simulate(params)
  OF <- gFun(out,0,5)
  return(OF)
}
```

The objective function is called from the `optim` function with some tolerance settings.

```
fitval=optim(par=parms,fn=OFfun,method="SANN",control = list(abstol = 1e-2))
summary(fitval)
```

My issue is that the optimization doesn't stop if the OFfun == 0.
I have tried with the condition below:

```
  if (OF == 0){ 
    opt <- options(show.error.messages=FALSE) 
    on.exit(options(opt)) 
    stop()
  }
```

it works but it doesn't return the OF back to `optim` and therefore I don't get the `fitval` info with estimated parameters.

**Issue 2**

Another issue is that the solver sometimes crashes and aborts the entire optimisation. I would like to harvest many solution sets for different initial guesses - so I need to handle failed simulations. probably related to issue 1.

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: First: Don't use the SANN method in `optim`, it's neither reliable nor efficient. Second: if you are going to apply Simulated Annealing, there is the package *GenSA* with a state-of-the-art implementation. Third: *GenSA* has a control option to stop the optimization process when a certain minimum level has been reached.  
In my understanding this is what you are asking for. For other stochastic solvers see the [Optimization](https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=Optimization) task view.

Comment: Question related to GenSA, I run the following   fitval=GenSA(par=log(parms),
               fn=OFfun,
               lower=log(p_min),
               upper=log(p_max),
               control = list(maxit=maxIter))
but it doen't respect the maxit setting, any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Open a new question ... and supply some reproducible code.

Comment: From the R Journal paper: 'maxit: Integer. Maximum number of iterations of the algorithm. Default value is 5000, which could be increased by the user for the optimization of a very complicated objective function.' there is nothing about being able to decrease it. (Source: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013/RJ-2013-002/RJ-2013-002.pdf). Supplying code is not straightforward as it is implemeted using proprietary package. Fortunately, using 'max.time: Numeric. Maximum running time in seconds' I can achieve what I need,